# It doesn't mean that only the marketers made customers purchase their products/ their own products?

Tags: possessive-pronouns, attachment-ambiguity

- "He made him buy ***his*** products."
- "It doesn't mean that only the marketers made customers purchase ***their*** products."

who do these possessive pronouns refer to? is it the doer who made that purchase or the one(s) who convinced the others to buy the products?

Comment: Because of the lack of context and supporting information, the referents of those words can't be determined from the sentences.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty generally, what do these possessive pronouns refer to?

Comment: They refer to someone previously mentioned, but without context it's impossible to know _who_.

Comment: @KateBunting I get it, it depends on the context, basically, my intent for this sentence "He made him buy his products." was to say that *him* buys the products of the person who was convincing the other. and due to this context, using *his* would be correct.

Comment: That's not what I meant by context. You would need to know from earlier sentences the names or occupations of 'he' and 'him' so as  to make an intelligent guess as to whose products were being bought.

Comment: Please edit to show the context in which you found these sentences. If you invented them yourself, the answer is that one sentence alone is sometimes not enough to make a meaning clear. Voting to close until edited.

Comment: @KateBunting gotcha!

Answer (score 1):

> He made him buy his products.

As @Jack O'Flaherty said, the sentence is ambiguous.

The person convincing the customer to buy may not be the product seller.  For example, he may be a tour guide bringing this tourist to a shop.

The second example explains this point.

If such an utterance appears out of nowhere and if I must make a guess, I would interpret *his* as referring to *He*.

Comment: I agree that the right context is necessary because *his* can also be interpreted as referring to *Him*.

Comment: Say, a seller is unable to sell his products and is forced by his distributor to buy them himself, under the contract?  I have not encountered such situations but can't rule this out.

Comment: The use of pronouns is heavily influenced by the listener judging what's the likely situation, based on imagining what is happening. Compare "He shot him in his leg" with "He shot him with his gun". In the former, "his" (fairly unambiguously) refers to "him", in the latter it probably refers to "He" (it's natural for the shooter to own the gun) but might refer to "him" (gun was stolen), or maybe even someone else had the gun before. "He shot him in his kitchen" has even fewer clues.

Comment: @hwkal In absolute isolation, I would guess that in "He made him buy his products", the "his" would refer to "he". But if I said "The contractor pressured the passerby to buy the shopkeep's wares. He made him buy his products," "he" would refer to "contractor", "him" to "passerby", and "his" to "shopkeep". It is truly dependent on context.

Comment: @StuartF your examples really helped me, Thanks

Comment: @YonKuma Thanks for your explanation buddy. Appreciated!